# Added Container Views and SubViews Disappeared using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uistoryboard

I am building a user interface using storyboards.  In order to make my screen do what I want when the screen rotates I embedded my existing views/controls in a UIView (using Xcode, Editor, Embed In).  My storyboard looks like I want it to.[image: storyboard showing two container views]  BUT when I run the app NONE of the controls appears on the screen.  [image].  The hierarchy and constraints all seem to be correct (no errors or advisory comments [image: view hierarchy].
What am I doing wrong?  What did I do to cause these controls to disappear?  The container views are not opaque and alpha is either 0 or otherwise low as can be seen by the background image.  What do I misunderstand?

Comment: Recommend that you use this scaled-down image for your second one -> http://i.imgur.com/OtTGrmf.png

Comment: Done Mr. Polywhirl...any suggestions for what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.  I must be misunderstanding something, but what solved the problem is setting the background of the container view to clear/color.  Unclicking Opaque didn't solve the problem.  The background image came through the container (if I set it up front), but for some reason the controls did not show up ... until I changed the background color.